# Why does gcc create redundant assembly code?

Tags: c, optimization, gcc, assembly, compiler-construction

I wanted to look into how certain C/C++ features were translated into assembly and I created the following file:

```
struct foo {
    int x;
    char y[0];
};

char *bar(struct foo *f)
{
    return f->y;
}
```

I then compiled this with `gcc -S` (and also tried with `g++ -S`) but when I looked at the assembly code, I was disappointed to find a trivial redundancy in the bar function that I thought `gcc` should be able to optimize away:

```
_bar:
Leh_func_begin1:
        pushq   %rbp
Ltmp0:
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp1:
        movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
        movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
        movabsq $4, %rcx
        addq    %rcx, %rax
        movq    %rax, -24(%rbp)
        movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
        movq    %rax, -16(%rbp)
        movq    -16(%rbp), %rax
        popq    %rbp
        ret
Leh_func_end1:
```

Among other things, the lines

```
        movq    %rax, -24(%rbp)
        movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
        movq    %rax, -16(%rbp)
        movq    -16(%rbp), %rax
```

seem pointlessly redundant. Is there any reason gcc (and possibly other compilers) cannot/does not optimize this away?

Comment: Please run gcc with -O switch to enable standard optimizations.

Comment: which version of gcc are you using?

Comment: More recent duplicate [Why does clang produce inefficient asm with -O0 (for this simple floating point sum)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53366394) which goes into more detail than the answers here about why some of this makes sense for consistent debugging.  (The basic point is the same, the answers here are correct.)  Related: [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I thought gcc should be able to optimize away.

From the [gcc manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html):

> Without any optimization option, the compiler's goal is to reduce the cost of compilation and to make debugging produce the expected results.

In other words, it doesn't optimize unless you ask it to. When I turn on optimizations using the `-O3` flag, gcc 4.4.6 produces much more efficient code:

```
bar:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        leaq    4(%rdi), %rax
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
```

For more details, see [Options That Control Optimization](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) in the manual.

Comment: Oh, I assumed standard optimizations would be on by default. Why aren't they?

Comment: @Matt: To quote the manual, "Without any optimization option, the compiler's goal is to reduce the cost of compilation and to make debugging produce the expected results."

Comment: @Matt And because the implementors so chose. Unless you score an answer from one of them here it's a futile question.

Answer (score 8):

The code the compiler generates without optimization is typically a straight instruction-by-instruction translation, and the instructions are not those of the program but those of an intermediate representation in which redundancy may have been introduced.

If you expect assembly without such redundant instructions, use `gcc -O -S`

The kind of optimization you were expecting is called [peephole optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peephole_optimization). Compilers usually have plenty of these, because unlike more global optimizations, they are cheap to apply and (generally) do not risk making the code worse—if applied towards the end of the compilation, at least.

In [this blog post](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2012/02/14/Overflows-1), I provide an example where both GCC and Clang may go as far as generating shorter 32-bit instructions when the integer type in the source code is 64-bit but only the lowest 32-bit of the result matter.